# Generic base class where T is also a generic base class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic base class something like:

```
public abstract class SomeThingBase<T> where T : class
```

I'd like to have another base class something like this:

```
public abstract class MangerBase<T> where T : SomeThingBase<T>
```

How do you accomplish this in C#? 
When trying to use ManagerBase like this it doesn't seem to work.

```
class TestManager : ManagerBase<TestSomething>
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see for yourself?

Comment: To be fair this doesnt seem to make much syntactic sense `where T : SomeThingBase<T>` I cant actually tell what you expect to happen here

Comment: It would have taken much less time to test this in ide, than questioning here

Comment: Sorry I did test this out several times, I could not work it out. Hence asking here. The error I have is: The Type SomeThingA must be convertible to SomeThingBase<SomeThingA> in order to use it as parameter T.

Comment: How do you initialize the MangerBase? Since it's abstract as well, I assume you have another class implementing that abstract class? You'd need something defining what <T> was either in the sub-class definition or  a generic class definition as well.

Comment: What kind of thing are you trying to do? What's your underlying need to do this?

Comment: Updated the question, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you have to pass your generic declarations in all the way from the top. This can get very messy, so avoid doing it.

```
public abstract class SomeThingBase<T> where T : class{ }
public abstract class ManagerBase<T, U> 
    where T : SomeThingBase<U>
    where U : class
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to define, but impossible to actually implement. Assuming you have the below definition:

```
    public abstract class SomeThingBase<T> where T : class { }
    public abstract class MangerBase<T> where T : SomeThingBase<T> { }
```

However, defining a class that implements `ManagerBase<T>` and `SomethingBase<T>` is impossible since multiple inheritance is not supported and `T` cannot meet both constraints without multiple inheritance the generic type.

Comment: So what is IBase in this example?

Comment: Something you don't need :) I mis-read part of your question and thought it would be a placeholder, but I'll take it out since it is not.

Comment: That generic declaration won't work. T can't be SomethingBase<T>. The definition would be circular.

Comment: The declaration works for the abstract classes, but you are right any implementation of the abstract classes will fail for the second class. @JoelEtherton